# How to redirect after a delay if an if statement if fulfilled

Tags: javascript

I've created a random site thing at the request of one of my friends that asks what the question is (The answer (An internet joke) Is "Do he got the booty?" At the moment I've got it to check the passcode given and write to the document depending on whether it's right or wrong. But I'd like it to, if the condition for the booty is fulfilled, redirect (After a 5 second delay) to Tumblr, the site of awesomeness.

This is my code so far :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The ultimate question</title>
      <style>
     body{
     background-color:rgb(238, 235, 229);
     }
     #scriptresult{
     font-family:calibri;
     font-size:26px;
     width:30%;
     margin-left:35%;
     text-align:center;
     margin-top:15%;
     border-color:rgb(91, 122, 221);
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:5px;
     padding:20px;
     background-color:rgb(240, 219, 200);    
     }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="scriptresult">


<script language="Javascript">
var passcode;
passcode = prompt("What is the ultimate question? (Make sure to include the ? at the end)");
passcode = (passcode.toUpperCase());
document.write("Your guess was" + " " + passcode);
if (passcode == "DO HE GOT A BOOTY?" || passcode == "DO HE GOT THE BOOTY?" || passcode == "DO HE GOT DA BOOTY?") {
    document.write("<br>Congratulations! You got da answer! Visit the awesomness!");
    else if (passcode == "DOCTOR WHO?" || passcode == "WHAT IS THE MEANING OF LIFE?" || passcode == "WHAT IS THE DOCTORS NAME?" || passcode == "WHAT IS THE DOCTOR'S NAME?") {
        document.write("<br>Not quite... But I love the guess! Think along the line of booty...<br><h6>(Hit refresh to try again)</h6>");
    } else {
        document.write("<br>Nope. That's wrong.<br><h6>(Hit refresh to try again)</h6>");
    }
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code into your success condition.

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="tumblr.com"},5000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked brilliantly! I'd vote you up but I need reputation... But yeah.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This will let you execute a function after five seconds.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do redirect here...
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your passing if statement:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = "www.tumblr.com"; //is this the right link?
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I just had to add the http:// to it and it worked fantastically! Thanks :)